# How to sort by relevance in the Flickr API?

Tags: javascript, json, flickr

I have the following function which utilizes the flickr API, however I wish to be able to sort the image order by relevance. Where can I specify this? Would it be in this function or the function that first stores available images(querying a search term for more than one api) in an array.

```
function printFlickrImages(){
    $("#output").append("<h3>Flickr</h3><p>"
            +availableImages["flickr"]["numImages"]+" images found from <a href='http://"
            +availableImages["flickr"]["url_pattern"]+"'>"
            +availableImages["flickr"]["url_pattern"]+"</a></p>");

    for (var i in availableImages["flickr"]["images"]){
        var url_comps = availableImages["flickr"]["images"][i].split("/");
        var photo_id = url_comps[url_comps.length-2];

        $.getJSON(flickr_url+photo_id, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.stat == "ok" && data.photo.usage.candownload == 1){
                    var flickr_image_url = "http://farm"+data.photo.farm
                                            +".staticflickr.com/"+data.photo.server
                                            +"/"+data.photo.id+"_"+data.photo.secret+"_z.jpg";
                    console.log(flickr_image_url);
                    $("#output").append("<img src='"+flickr_image_url+"'>");
                }else{
                    console.log("Image protected.");
                }
        });
    }
}//close printFlickr Images
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [flickrapi module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/flickrapi):

```
var Flickr = require("flickrapi"),
    flickrOptions = {
      api_key: "your key",
      secret: "your secret",
        user_id:"your userid"
        access_token: "your access token",
        access_token_secret: "your token secret"
    };

Flickr.authenticate(flickrOptions, function(error, flickr) {
  // we can now use "flickr" as our API object
    flickr.photos.search({ // this is searching for photos
      text: "whatever search you want to do",
      safe_search: 1,
      content_type: 1,
      sort: "relevance", // this is where you sort by relevance
      // you can also sort by  date-posted-asc, date-posted-desc, date-taken-asc, date-taken-desc, interestingness-desc, interestingness-asc
      page: 1,
      per_page: 10
    }, function(err, result) {
      console.log(result.photos.photo) // this displays the ten photos returned by this search
      console.log(result.photos.photo[0]) // this displays the first of your ten photos
    });
});
```

Note where I use `sort: "relevance"`. You can also sort by  date-posted-asc, date-posted-desc, date-taken-asc, date-taken-desc, interestingness-desc, interestingness-asc

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `&sort=relevance` as a parameter to the initial call of [flickr.photos.search](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html), which is not shown in your code snippet.  That is, wherever it is in the code that populates `availableImages`, add the `&sort` parameter to the API call.